# How to use css visibility property with SlideUp and SlideDown jquery functions?

Tags: jquery

I am using the JQuery `slideUp` and `slideDown` functions to hide and show some divs with animation.

But it uses the css `display` property for hiding and showing the divs and I want to use the css `visibility` property instead of `display`.

What should I do?

Comment: What is wrong with the display property?

Comment: Why do you need to use `visibility` instead of `display`?

Comment: do you need this in your specific situation?
  if so, describe it more.

Comment: I am using the visibility because I want that the space should be allocated to that hidden divs but will not appear in the browser simply.

Answer (score 0):

To use `visibility` use `fadeIn` and `fadeOut`.

Comment: it also uses the display property.

Answer (score 0):

slideDown / slideUp effectively animates height, so use `$.animate()` with setting height to 0 and as callback - visibility to hidden, and for slideDown set visibility to visible and animate the height to the correct value